# Please ban the [access] tag

Tags: support, tag-block-request

The [access](/questions/tagged/access) tag was used for a wide range of topics:

- file permissions
- member access modifiers
- access violations
- MS Access
- anything related to authorization
- file I/O
- ...

I went through those questions and retagged them. Can we ban this tag now?

Comment: They seem okay on SciFiFantasy

Comment: @random: I do not understand. What do you mean?

Comment: After a day or so users who don't have tag creation rights won't be able to use it. Those that do can re-create it, but should really know better. Seriously.

Comment: @Mpelletier: the [access] tag is reintroduced every day, so perhaps it never gets at the point where new users cannot use it. In any case, you only need 250 rep to create new tags which isn't very high.

Comment: Access is creeping back again. I wonder is it possible to have certain ambiguous tags just default to nothing?